# Build Failed: error: make directory File exists

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I have an app in the app store and have built and released several updates without issue. I am working on a major update, but having a significant error that I have been Googling for over a week now.

I can build the app for the simulator, but when I try to build for iOS device (such as with my iPhone 6 plugged in) or Archive (so that I can distribute via TestFlight), I get the same error every time. Full error posted below.

Things I have tried:

- Cleaning the Project
- Restarting xCode
- Restarting my Mac - Deleting the Derived Data folder
- Updating xCode
- Deleting and Reinstalling xCode

The actual error received is:

> CpResource Libraries/AppIRater/en.lproj
>   /Users/terrencewilliams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMBox-gbfftxbyzlmadeazsrisoquokaxr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SMBox/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/SMBox.app/en.lproj
>       cd "/Users/terrencewilliams/Desktop/APP/SMBox/APP Builds - v.2.0/SMBox2 4"
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -strip-debug-symbols -strip-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip
>   -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/terrencewilliams/Desktop/APP/SMBox/APP\ Builds\ -\ v.2.0/SMBox2\ 4/Libraries/AppIRater/en.lproj
>   /Users/terrencewilliams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMBox-gbfftxbyzlmadeazsrisoquokaxr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SMBox/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/SMBox.app
>
> error: make directory /Users/terrencewilliams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMBox-gbfftxbyzlmadeazsrisoquokaxr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SMBox/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/SMBox.app/en.lproj:
>   File exists

I really need to get this update rolling, but can't seem to actually build it. Can anyone advise if there might be some underlying cause that I don't see relating to the derived data folder?

Comment: It looks like there are two en.lproj files being included in the build: one from SMBox and one from ApplRater.  I had a similar build problem when my project contained two en.lproj files from two different settings bundles.  If possible, removing one might help.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem by removing duplicate bundle from my project which I have added from other source. Look for duplicate copy of en.lproj and remove it this might solve ur problem.

Comment: Yeah that was it for me. One of the Pods had a duplicate file.

Answer (score 10):

My issue was due to a merge conflict I had the same dynamic framework in "Embedded Binaries" listed twice.  Removing the duplicate framework allowed me to build successfully.

Answer (score 3):

This path exists as a file (whereas itthe build is trying to create a directory): /Users/terrencewilliams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMBox-gbfftxbyzlmadeazsrisoquokaxr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SMBox/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/SMBox.app/en.lproj

I suggest you just delete /Users/terrencewilliams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and rebuild.

Yes, I realize you said you deleted the DerivedData folder already.  Did you really delete *that* one?  If so, what is creating the en.lproj?  You might want to just search through the build log for it.

Comment: Only delete the content of the DerivedData folder. Do not delete the folder it self

Comment: @Christoffer why do you say that?  The build system will recreate it as soon as you kick off the next build, so there's no reason to differentiate.

Comment: you might be right, but read in other forums that it could make it fail. Might only be for some versions of xcode. So I am saying it and doing it like that just to be on the safe side :)